# android: move a view on touch move: sometime ACTION_MOVE is not coming

Tags: android

I am implementing pull to close functionality. If user pull the current layout then it will animate and then close the screen. But sometime I am not getting ACTION_MOVE event and application is not able to check if there is any pull event happened.

PFB my code snippet

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getEdgeFlags() != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mIsDragged) {
                lastYPosition= event.getY();
                lastXPosition = event.getX();
                return true;
            }
            else{
                int diffY = (int)(event.getY() - lastYPosition);
                int diffX = (int)(event.getX() - lastXPosition);

                //Check if the action was Pull
                if(diffY<0 && (Math.abs(diffY) > Math.abs(diffX)) && Math.abs(diffY) > mTouchSlop){
                    mIsDragged = true;

                    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 50, 50);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(400);
                    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    draggedLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            ((Activity)mContext).finish();
                            ((Activity)mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
                        }
                    });
                    draggedLayout.startAnimation(anim);
                }
                else{
                    mIsDragged = false;
                }
                lastYPosition = event.getY();
                lastXPosition = event.getX();
                return true;
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastYPosition = event.getY();
            lastXPosition = event.getX();
            mIsDragged = false;
            return true;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !mIsDragged){
        lastXPosition = event.getX();
        lastYPosition = event.getY();
        mIsDragged = false;
    }           
  //        return mIsDragged;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are returning false in onTouchEvent:

```
if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getEdgeFlags() != 0) {
    return false;
}
```

If the event returns false the system will propagate the event to other views to see if they will take care of this event.

The documentation for onInterceptTouchEvent() has rules on how to implement onTouchEvent() and what to return:

```
For OnInterceptTouchEvent():

2) The down event will be handled either by a child of this view group, or given to your own 
onTouchEvent() method to handle; this means you should implement onTouchEvent() to return true, 
so you will continue to see the rest of the gesture (instead of looking for a parent view to 
handle it). Also, by returning true from onTouchEvent(), you will not receive any following 
events in onInterceptTouchEvent() and all touch processing must happen in onTouchEvent() like 
normal.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: I have tried to return true but still it is not working

Comment: Is there a specific motion that causes the ACTION_DOWN to not be trigger?

Comment: I had used fling action to pull this view and getting ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_CANCEL event

Comment: So you are not triggering ACTION_MOVE all the time or there are specific instance of fling action that does not trigger ACTION_MOVE?

Comment: There are some instances of fling action that are not triggering ACTION_MOVE

Comment: My guess is that there are certain area in the layout that may not be attached to the listener (ie Actionbar). Try printing out the specific coordinates to see where the trigger are not registering